# How to Conditionally Load @Font-Faces via CSS3?

Tags: html, css, fonts, css3, embed

Curerntly, when you use a beautiful font, like for example the multiligual `Calibri` fotn (a win7 font), then it even downloads eventhough a user has the font already installed, when i use the following css:

```
@charset "utf-8";  
@font-face {
    font-family: Calibri;
    src: url('http://blabla.com/calibri.eot')
    }
```

**However:** this font is 400 kb gzipped, and i would like it to *ONLY* download, if the font is NOT present or installed by that name / family name, right?

**Question:** Is this possible to setup a neat conditional rule for this, for modern browsers (say IE8+, Firefox 3+ etc). How to implement it? Thanks for any and all clues!

Comment: Maybe this should be a question for Stack Overflow?

Comment: Asper the FAQ this question belongs on Doctype

Comment: Silly John, why do you close off my interesting, on topic pro questions? Other people react upon and say INTERESTING (see below) I am answered below, fortunately before you closed me again. I demand a re-vote from ANOTHER moderator and hereby dismiss your domination as unjustice. This is a good question and received a good ansewr. You all the time cause me unhappyness by jealously closing off my interesting questions. Please go do something that is GOOD for the community, or else I will report this to the highest bosses about your unjustified, jealous activities against my little questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Calibri;
    src:
         local('Calibri'),
         url('http://blabla.com/calibri.eot');
}
```

[Source and more detailed explanation](http://www.broken-links.com/2009/06/30/checking-for-installed-fonts-with-font-face-and-local/).

Comment: Interesting... I had thought that if you omitted a `local` directive, it would simply search for the name given in `font-family`, and that's why you need to specify a smiley face for `local` if you wanted to force the browser to always use the online version.

Comment: Thanks very much Betamax &  Lèse majesté! I think that is it! This answer make my website much more pro.  i guesse i have to call the fond then by `font-family: "Calibri", Arial` with double quotes around the fontname right?